# First Derivative of Bond Price

Tags: calculus

Can you please show the steps of taking the first derivative of this equation with respect to y:

$$
P=C\left[\frac{1-{\cfrac{1}{(1+y)^n}}}{y} \right]+\cfrac{M}{(1+y)^n}
$$

And turning it into this: 
$$
\frac{dP}{dY}=\frac{C}{y^2}[{1-\frac{1}{(1+y)^n}}]+\cfrac{n(M-\frac{C}{y})}{(1+y)^{n+1}}
$$
Could you also please tell me the rules you used when you did the first derivative? I think for the first expression you use the power rule, however, I am not sure. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$P(y)=C\left( \frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y(1+y)^n}\right)+\frac{M}{(1+y)^n}.$$

Differentiation with respect to y yields
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}y}=C\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\frac{1}{y}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\frac{1}{y(1+y)^n}\right)+\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\frac{M}{(1+y)^n},$$

where we make use of the fact that

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \sum f_k = \sum \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} f_k.$$

Furthermore, applying both the power rule and quotient rule, we have
$$=C\left(-\frac{1}{y^2} +\frac{ny+y+1}{y^2(1+y)^{n+1}}\right)-\frac{Mn}{(1+y)^{n+1}}.$$

Tidying this up a bit will yield the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be off by a sign...

\begin{align*}
\frac{dP}{dy}
&= C \cdot \left[\frac{1}{y}\frac{d}{dy}\left(1-\frac{1}{(1+y)^n}\right) + \left(1-\frac{1}{(1+y)^n}\right)\frac{d}{dy}\frac{1}{y}\right] + M \frac{d}{dy}\frac{1}{(1+y)^n}\\
&= C \cdot \left[\frac{1}{y} \frac{n}{(1+y)^{n+1}}-\left(1-\frac{1}{(1+y)^n}\right)\frac{1}{y^2}\right]-M \frac{n}{(1+y)^{n+1}}\\
&= -\frac{C}{y^2} \left(1-\frac{1}{(1+y)^n}\right) + \frac{n\left(\frac{C}{y}-M\right)}{(1+y)^{n+1}}
\end{align*}

[First line is product rule and power rule]